# Sum values of same key that have same user id also retain there date as key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, sum

I am trying to add up the `totalPlayed` values for each `user_id`. I don't want to change the overall structure of the array, I just want to condense the `events` subarrays by summing the `totalPlayed` values.

Here is a sample array as json:

```
[
  {
    "date": "May 29",
    "date_start": "2018-05-29 05:00:00",
    "date_end": "2018-05-30 04:59:59",
    "interval": 29,
    "calDay": "29 days ago",
    "events": [
      {
        "totalPlayed": 184,
        "user_id": 479
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 906,
        "user_id": 479
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 400,
        "user_id": 1446
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 500,
        "user_id": 1446
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "May 30",
    "date_start": "2018-05-30 05:00:00",
    "date_end": "2018-05-31 04:59:59",
    "interval": 28,
    "calDay": "28 days ago",
    "events": [
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1469,
        "user_id": 1626
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1482,
        "user_id": 1690
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1434,
        "user_id": 1690
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like this result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'date' => 'May 29',
    'date_start' => '2018-05-29 05:00:00',
    'date_end' => '2018-05-30 04:59:59',
    'interval' => 29,
    'calDay' => '29 days ago',
    'events' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'totalPlayed' => 1090,
        'user_id' => 479,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'totalPlayed' => 900,
        'user_id' => 1446,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'date' => 'May 30',
    'date_start' => '2018-05-30 05:00:00',
    'date_end' => '2018-05-31 04:59:59',
    'interval' => 28,
    'calDay' => '28 days ago',
    'events' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'totalPlayed' => 1469,
        'user_id' => 1626,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'totalPlayed' => 2916,
        'user_id' => 1690,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I tried the following function but it is not working for me.

```
function computeOutcome($array) {
    $result=array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $id=$item['user_id'];
        if (isset($result[$id])) {
            $result[$id]=$result[$id]+$item['time_played'];
        } else {
            $result[$id]=$item['time_played'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I do not see an element keyed as `time_played`.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Key is totalPlayed. Sorry for that.

Comment: What is the input to your function, is it the first snippet of code you provided as it is?

Comment: Yes sir. As it is.

Comment: Can you output that Json here instead? That page is impossible to use on mobiles.

Comment: Hi mickmackusa and Andreas. I am editing my question to put json of array .

Comment: Json. JavaScript... Ok sorry for the bad joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using temporary keys on your deep subarrays offers improved performance versus iterated `in_array()` calls.  See inline comments for more explanations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S272H))

```
function computeOutcome($array) {
    foreach ($array as &$set) {  // modify by reference
        $tmp = [];  // use a fresh temporary array for each date-set
        foreach ($set['events'] as $record) {
            $id = $record['user_id'];
            if (isset($tmp[$id])) {
                $tmp[$id]['totalPlayed'] += $record['totalPlayed'];  // increase the tally
            } else {
                $tmp[$id] = $record;  // store the whole row
            }
        }
        $set['events'] = array_values($tmp);  // remove temporary keys
    }
    return $array;
}

$json = <<<JSON
[
  {
    "date": "May 29",
    "date_start": "2018-05-29 05:00:00",
    "date_end": "2018-05-30 04:59:59",
    "interval": 29,
    "calDay": "29 days ago",
    "events": [
      {
        "totalPlayed": 184,
        "user_id": 479
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 906,
        "user_id": 479
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 400,
        "user_id": 1446
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 500,
        "user_id": 1446
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "May 30",
    "date_start": "2018-05-30 05:00:00",
    "date_end": "2018-05-31 04:59:59",
    "interval": 28,
    "calDay": "28 days ago",
    "events": [
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1469,
        "user_id": 1626
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1482,
        "user_id": 1690
      },
      {
        "totalPlayed": 1434,
        "user_id": 1690
      }
    ]
  }
]
JSON;

var_export(computeOutcome(json_decode($json, true)));
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes to explain.  I am slow on my phone.

Comment: you are right brother. I believe your code is much faster than other. Thank you mate.

Comment: I really sorry about that. I was thinking that you are not with me. So I picked that one

Comment: Yes, sorry I was much slower to post without my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your main array is called `$data`, this solution builds a new array with summed values, you can then replace the original array with the new one created:

```
function computeOutcome($array) {
    $events = [];
    foreach ($array as $evt) {
        if (in_array($evt['user_id'], array_column($events, 'user_id'))) {
            $key = array_search($evt['user_id'], array_column($events, 'user_id'));
            $events[$key]['totalPlayed'] += $evt['totalPlayed'];
        } else {
            $events[] = $evt;
        }
    }
    return $events;
}

$data['events'] = computeOutcome($data['events']);
```

---

**EDIT:**
As you have a **JSON** string, I got the same result as before doing this (assuming your JSON string is called `$json`):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Still using the function I wrote before
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i]['events'] = computeOutcome($data[$i]['events']);
}

// Print result
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

---

**Documentation:**

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Hi AymDev, I am getting `Undefined index: user_id` error. Could you please edit your solution.

Comment: `in_array()` is slow.  Find a better way.

Comment: @Neeraj I tested it and it works, did you send `$data['events']` to the function and not just `$data` ?

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa I did not know that. Do you have a good link about this issue or just "Find a better way." ? Anyway, the other answer looks much better.

Comment: I'll provide an educational answer if the OP provides a ready-to-use variable.  This type of question is asked roughly every 48 hours.  This one may be different, but it is categorically the same as many others.

Comment: Hi AymDev. Thanks again. Here is the fiddle of my array https://jsfiddle.net/645e2jh1/. You can check it for better help.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes this is the issue with SO, we often come across the same issues. I edited OP's question, you can use the variables now

Comment: @Neeraj is your array from **PHP** or **JavaScript** ? Is this a **JSON** response maybe ?

Comment: I honestly think that misrepresents the real array structure.  I expect to see an additional level in the array which allows the storage of multiple date sets.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am really sorry if I confused you. All I want to put less code so people don't feel messy question. You can check json or fiddle to get exact idea. Thanks again

Comment: @Neeraj I updated my answer. This does not sum `totalPlayed` across days as this is not requested (looking to your expected output).

Comment: Hi @AymDev. I want some across days. I want the separate result for May 29 and May 30 etc. Could you please edit your code.

Comment: @AymDev. I don't know how to thank yours. Your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much mate for your help. Thanks, everyone for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column to find the user id, array_intersect to find the respective values and array_sum to sum the values.

```
$data =json_decode('
[
{
"date": "May 29",
"date_start": "2018-05-29 05:00:00",
"date_end": "2018-05-30 04:59:59",
"interval": 29,
"calDay": "29 days ago",
"events": [
  {
    "totalPlayed": 184,
    "user_id": 479
  },
  {
    "totalPlayed": 906,
    "user_id": 479
  },
  {
    "totalPlayed": 400,
    "user_id": 1446
  },
  {
    "totalPlayed": 500,
    "user_id": 1446
  }

 ]
},
{
"date": "May 30",
"date_start": "2018-05-30 05:00:00",
"date_end": "2018-05-31 04:59:59",
"interval": 28,
"calDay": "28 days ago",
"events": [
  {
    "totalPlayed": 1469,
    "user_id": 1626
  },
  {
    "totalPlayed": 1482,
    "user_id": 1690
  },
  {
    "totalPlayed": 1434,
    "user_id": 1690
  }
]
}
]', true);
Foreach($data as $key => $arr){
    $userid = array_column($arr["events"], "user_id");
    $played = array_column($arr["events"], "totalPlayed");
    Foreach(array_unique($userid) as $id){
        $temp = array_intersect_key($played, array_intersect($userid, [$id]));
        $new[$key]['events']['date'] = $arr['date'];
        $new[$key]['events'][] = ['total played' => array_sum($temp), 'user_id' => $id];
    }
}
Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/G1jKI

This will only loop the unique userids instead of the full array.

In the future you can post arrays as Json or as var_export and it will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Andreas. Thanks for your suggestion. I have created a fiddle with my code. Here is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/645e2jh1/. Please take a look so you can understand actual structure of my array. Thanks mate for your help.

Comment: Hi @Andreas. Did you check fiddle I provided? I think we also need an outer loop to access `events` key. I am getting `Undefined index: events` error.

Comment: I did but as I wrote to you I can't use that page. It's impossible to use that page on a mobile